# NASで使っていたHDDからデータを復旧したい

Tags: linux, raid

asustorのAS3102Tを使っています。
先日、NASにアクセスしたら初期設定の画面が表示されたので、急いで電源を切り新しいHDDを買ってきて入れ替えました。古いHDDはUSBの外付けボックス経由でNASにつないでいます。
この状態で、古いHDD内のファイルを復旧する方法を知りたいです。

NASは組み込みLinux上で動いていて、その上でJBODのRAIDを組んでおりbtrfsでフォーマットしています。試したことは次の通りです。

```
root@agartha $ mdadm --examine /dev/sdd3
/dev/sdd3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 1e748aef:a00558dc:095d0302:b45acb4e
           Name : agartha:2  (local to host agartha)
  Creation Time : Mon Mar 15 07:51:13 2021
     Raid Level : linear
   Raid Devices : 1

 Avail Dev Size : 15618876176 (7447.66 GiB 7996.86 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 0
    Data Offset : 262144 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=262056 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 2b838137:a13c43b5:36c36506:590cd536

    Update Time : Mon Mar 15 07:51:13 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 3c2a88 - correct
         Events : 0

       Rounding : 0K

   Device Role : spare
   Array State : A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
root@agartha $ mdadm --assemble /dev/md2 --force --run --verbose /dev/sdd3
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md2
mdadm: /dev/sdd3 is identified as a member of /dev/md2, slot -1.
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 0 of /dev/md2
mdadm: added /dev/sdd3 to /dev/md2 as -1
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md2: Invalid argument
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.
root@agartha $ dmesg|tail
[ 2033.218597] md: pers->run() failed ...
[ 2033.218772] md: md9 stopped.
[ 2048.095630] md: md2 stopped.
[ 2048.122824] md/linear:md2: not enough drives present. Aborting!
[ 2048.122830] md: pers->run() failed ...
[ 2048.122991] md: md2 stopped.
[ 4267.871106] md: md2 stopped.
[ 4267.893086] md/linear:md2: disk numbering problem. Aborting!
[ 4267.893093] md: pers->run() failed ...
[ 4267.893280] md: md2 stopped.
root@agartha $
```

以上です。そのほかに必要な情報があれば教えてください
よろしく、お願いします。

**追記:**

device roleがスペアだったので、activeだった場合の出力

```
root@agartha $ mdadm --assemble /dev/md2 --force --run --verbose /dev/sdf3
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md2
mdadm: /dev/sdf3 is identified as a member of /dev/md2, slot 0.
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 2 of /dev/md2
mdadm: added /dev/sdf3 to /dev/md2 as 0
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md2: Invalid argument
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.
```

21:30 追記
fdisk -l /dev/sd* の結果

```
Disk /dev/sda: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FC762E12-CB50-4A75-9CAC-2A9D9FE24126

Device       Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048      524287      522240  255M Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2   524288     4718591     4194304    2G Linux RAID
/dev/sda3  4718592     8912895     4194304    2G Linux RAID
/dev/sda4  8912896 15628052479 15619139584  7.3T Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sda1: 255 MiB, 267386880 bytes, 522240 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda2: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda3: 2 GiB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda4: 7.3 TiB, 7996999467008 bytes, 15619139584 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D9477EE0-6599-477F-99DB-424FE08DC299

Device       Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   524288     4712455     4188168    2G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb2  4718592     8908807     4190216    2G Linux RAID
/dev/sdb3  8912896 15628051215 15619138320  7.3T Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sdb1: 2 GiB, 2144342016 bytes, 4188168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb2: 2 GiB, 2145390592 bytes, 4190216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdb3: 7.3 TiB, 7996998819840 bytes, 15619138320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes




Disk /dev/sdd: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B9A7FDFB-150B-4C8D-97E0-1933166D5B45

Device       Start     End Sectors Size Type
/dev/sdd1   524288 4714503 4190216   2G Linux RAID
/dev/sdd2  4718592 8908807 4190216   2G Linux RAID
/dev/sdd3  8912896 8912903       8   4K Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sdd1: 2 GiB, 2145390592 bytes, 4190216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd2: 2 GiB, 2145390592 bytes, 4190216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdd3: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/sde: 5.5 TiB, 6001175126016 bytes, 11721045168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 37554534-080E-4CA0-B019-C7B2ADABB02E

Device     Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1   2048 11721045134 11721043087  5.5T Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sde1: 5.5 TiB, 6001174060544 bytes, 11721043087 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdf: 7.3 TiB, 8001563222016 bytes, 15628053168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 92F97BEA-8D27-40EF-A3F9-001271E6A476

Device       Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdf1   524288     4714503     4190216    2G Linux RAID
/dev/sdf2  4718592     8908807     4190216    2G Linux RAID
/dev/sdf3  8912896 15628051215 15619138320  7.3T Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sdf1: 2 GiB, 2145390592 bytes, 4190216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdf2: 2 GiB, 2145390592 bytes, 4190216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sdf3: 7.3 TiB, 7996998819840 bytes, 15619138320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

21:56 追記
試しに、raid1だった/dev/sdf1を認識させたときのログ。うまく認識しているみたい

```
bash-4.4# mdadm --assemble /dev/md2 --verbose --force --run /dev/sdf1
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md2
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 is identified as a member of /dev/md2, slot 0.
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 2 of /dev/md2
mdadm: added /dev/sdf1 to /dev/md2 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md2 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2).
bash-4.4# mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Thu Nov 14 07:49:04 2019
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 2095104 (2046.34 MiB 2145.39 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 2095104 (2046.34 MiB 2145.39 MB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 1
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Mon Mar 15 20:51:38 2021
          State : clean, degraded 
 Active Devices : 1
Working Devices : 1
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

           Name : AS3102T-EC2E:0
           UUID : 9b6f13e4:dee13992:387d90bb:d415e565
         Events : 1592

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       81        0      active sync   /dev/sdf1
       2       0        0        2      removed
bash-4.4# mount -o ro -t ext4 0 /dev/md2 /share/disk/
bash-4.4# ls -a /share/disk/
.           ..          .@system    .@trashcan  etc         lost+found  usr
bash-4.4# exit
exit
```

3月20日 0:30追記
つぎのようにして、device role: spareを外すことが出来ました。ただ、色々と試しながらなのと、記憶に頼っているので間違いがあるかも知れません。

1. 古くなって使わなくなっていた3TBのHDDを仮RAID用として用意。外付けHDDボックスにこの3TBと回復させたいHDDをセットする
2. partedを使ってRAID用に3GBほど母領域を確保
3. `mdadm --create /dev/md2 --level=1 --raid-devices=1 --force /dev/sde1`として、先ほどの領域をraidとして用意。
4. `mkfs.btrfs /dev/md2`として、RAID領域をbtrfsでフォーマット
5. `mdadm --manage /dev/ms2 --add --force /dev/sdf3`として回復させたいHDD(のパーティション)を強引に追加
6. NASを再起動する。(この前にtestdiskかfdiskでファイルシステムの確認をしたかも知れません)
7. 再起動後、`mdadm --create /dev/md2 --level=linear --raid-devices=2 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf3`としてraidを認識させる。

これで/dev/sdf3がActive deviceとなったみたいです。
detailとexamineの結果は次の通りです

```
root@@agartha # mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 19 05:49:45 2021
     Raid Level : linear
     Array Size : 7810615688 (7448.78 GiB 7998.07 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Fri Mar 19 05:49:45 2021
          State : clean 
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

       Rounding : 0K

           Name : agartha:2  (local to host agartha)
           UUID : 57d3e44a:10b40824:758be441:11b25465
         Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       65        0      active sync   /dev/sde1
       1       8       83        1      active sync   /dev/sdf3
root@@agartha # mdadm --examine /dev/sde1
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 57d3e44a:10b40824:758be441:11b25465
           Name : agartha:2  (local to host agartha)
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 19 05:49:45 2021
     Raid Level : linear
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 2095104 (1023.17 MiB 1072.69 MB)
  Used Dev Size : 0
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1960 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : fc44704e:90201d2e:b9046077:fe56c916

    Update Time : Fri Mar 19 05:49:45 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 379c1fdc - correct
         Events : 0

       Rounding : 0K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
root@@agartha # mdadm --examine /dev/sdf3
/dev/sdf3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 57d3e44a:10b40824:758be441:11b25465
           Name : agartha:2  (local to host agartha)
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 19 05:49:45 2021
     Raid Level : linear
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 15619136272 (7447.78 GiB 7997.00 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 0
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1960 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e8aa91ec:6b14ca43:db393baa:0008eabf

    Update Time : Fri Mar 19 05:49:45 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 6a3f82dd - correct
         Events : 0

       Rounding : 0K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
root@@agartha #
```

Comment: コマンドの実行結果は「新しいHDDに交換した後」ということでしょうか？

Comment: そうです。NASに新しいHDDを入れて初期化した後、旧HDDを外付けUSBに入れました。その後、コンソールで外付けにした旧HDDに対してmdadmを試みた結果となります。

Comment: "古いHDD" とは元々のRAID構成の「壊れたHDD」「異常なしのHDD」どちらを指していますか？ / 外付けHDD(ケース)はRAID対応しているのでしょうか？ / 物理的なディスクの構成が故障の前後でどうなっているのかをもう少し具体的にまとめてもらうとよいかもしれません。

Comment: 古いHDDは、元々NASに入っていて壊れたHDDです。自分の作業のミスでNASがHDDを設定済みと認識しなくなったためソフト的に壊れたと判断しています。  外付けHDDケースはYotta Master製のものでHDDが4台入りますが、すべて別々のHDDとして認識しています。

Comment: なお、device roleがspareになったのは外付けHDDにファイルバックアップ用に新しいHDDを入れて、そこにmdadmでLVMを作成し、さらに壊れたHDDのbtrfsのパーティションを追加したらspareになりました。質問後、蒸気の処理をしたために追記のactiveだったHDDのroleが現時点でspareになっています。

Comment: fdisk -l /dev/sd* の出力です。 /dev/sda,sdbはNAS内に新しく入れたHDD、/dev/sdd,sdfが最初にNASに入っていて初期設定画面が表示されるようになったHDD、/dev/sdeが復旧したデータのバックアップ用のHDD(btrfsでフォーマットした)ものです。

Comment: 3/20 に追記された内容は、ひとまず解決したという事でしょうか？もしそうであれば、質問文への追記ではなく個別の回答として投稿してみてください。

Comment: 質問はあくまで「質問」の体裁を保ってください。(完全でなくても) 解決方法であるなら追記ではなく **個別の回答** として投稿してください。 参考ヘルプ: [自分の質問に回答できますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

外付けHDDケースに入れた古い(壊れた)NASのHDDをRAIDボリュームとして認識するところまでできました。
HDDケースにNASのHDD2台をいれたあと、mdadmで強引にRAIDを作成すればいいようです。

```
root@@agartha # mdadm --create /dev/md2 --level=linear --raid-devices=2 --force /dev/sdd3 /dev/sde3
mdadm: /dev/sdd3 appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid1 devices=2 ctime=Sun Mar  7 18:33:37 2021
mdadm: /dev/sde3 appears to be part of a raid array:
       level=raid1 devices=2 ctime=Wed Mar  3 14:29:56 2021
Continue creating array? yes
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md2 started.
root@@agartha #
```

これでRAIDボリュームとして認識しました。ファイルなどのデータなどはいじられていないはずなので、マウントできればデータが復旧できると思います

2021年5月14日 追記

市販のファイル／ディスク復旧ソフトを使うことで復旧しました。
現時点では、ディスクスキャンが100%終了し、試しに一部のデータを復旧させました。

使用したのは、virtualhere( https://www.virtualhere.com/ ), ReclaiMe ( https://www.reclaime.com/ )の2つのソフトです。

まず、virtualhereサーバをNASにvirtualhereクライアントをWindowsにインストールします。
これで、NAS上の外付けUSBのHDDが、Windows上でUSBに繋がっているように見えます。

次にReclaiMeを起動します。ReclaiMeはLinux上のソフトウェアRAID( mdデバイス )を認識するので、mdデバイスをスキャンして見つかったファイルを復旧します。